# how fix, recovery problem uid LocalStorage ReactJS/ NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

to put you in context, I'm logging in and I'm on a page like my information or my profile.

I have a funny error, so I'm trying to recover data from. my BDD in order to correctly display the telephone number.

the 1st error is the following on my LIVE server when the page opens I have a 404 error which is displayed

and the second when I make a POSTMAN request

```
{
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'",
sqlState: '42S22',
index: 0,
sql: 'SELECT * from cartebleuuser where telephone=undefined'
}
```

I would like to be able to display the correct telephone which corresponds to the UID in my database

How can I fix this issue?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class Profile  extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   userProfile: null
     };
    }

getUserProfile = async (telephone) => {
 const res = await axios.get(
   `https://joke.fr/api/cartebleuuser${telephone}` 
 );
 this.setState({ userProfile: res.data });
 console.log(res.data);
}

componentDidMount() {
const user = localStorage.getItem("authUser");
console.log(user);
if (user) {
  const { id, telephone } = JSON.parse(user);
  this.getUserProfile(telephone);
 }
}

render() {
  const { userProfile } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
       {userProfile ? userProfile.telephone : "No user telephone"}
       </div>
      )
      }
    }
  export default Profile;
```

MyRoute on BDD

```
 app.get('/api/cartebleuuser', (req, res) => {
 const { telephone } = req.params;
 console.log(telephone);
 connection.query(`SELECT * from cartebleuuser where telephone=${telephone}`, (err, results) 
 => {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Erreur lors de la récupération des employés');
    } else {
    console.log(results);
    return res.json(results);
    }
  });
  });
```

BDD schéma.

```
{
"id": 62,
"telephone": "0202020202",
"uid": "dycjibu96zgmzc0KpGAqxKiUsMu2"
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your postman/curl request?

Comment: It also looks like `https://joke.fr/api/cartebleuuser${telephone}` is not valid in your case. Try `https://joke.fr/api/cartebleuuser?telephone=${telephone}`

Comment: @DaniR hello ,for postman my request is "https://joke.fr/api/cartebleuuser". and error is that   code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'SELECT * from cartebleuuser where telephone=undefined'
}
GET /api/cartebleuuser 500 2.055 ms - 46

Comment: @DaniR and on my live serv error was https://joke.fr/api/cartebleuusernull 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @DaniR 
I changed what you told me of course

Comment: Well, your URL does not match the requierd pattern `top-lvl-domain/path?key=value`. On server side you destructure a request parameter with `const { telephone } = req.params;` but you never set this parameter on your request. So in your query it will be undefind. Also in your postman/curl request you have to set these paramters. If you are not familier with the URL pattern have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL